# How to add an download link to users in my project

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my project i will be having an link like

```
 <a href="~/hello world.crx" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

I want the users to download files of different types. The file will be in the root folder. When i am clicking on the link it is displaying an error. This is the plugin to install in the chrome. If the user download this link and open then it will automatically add to the chrome.
How can i do this.

The file is not even downloading.

Comment: @Lloyd The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a valid path:

> ~/hello world.crx

The `~` character is for use server-side to denote the root of the application.  Client-side it has no meaning.  The browser doesn't know what the root of the application is (or what the application is at all), it's just sending requests to resources at addresses.  And it doesn't know what to do with that address.

You'll need to either use some server-side logic to translate that path into a browser-useable path, or manually make it a relative or absolute path.

If the ASP.NET MVC Framework isn't translating this for you then you're probably using a version that requires a little more manual work for it.  Try something like:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/hello world.crx")" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

(Note: This assumes the use of the Razor view engine.  If you're not using that then you'll want to use whatever your view engine equivalent is.)

Comment: ASP.NET should process out the `~/` to the correct path AFAIK.

Comment: @Lloyd: Depends on the version.  MVC4 does it fairly well, but I think all (or at least most) versions prior to that required using `@Url.Content`.

Comment: If it is only rar file then it is downloading other wise it is throwing an extension. Then how can i install the plugin there

Comment: @Naidu: It's possible that error may not be from the code, but instead from IIS itself.  Perhaps your web server is configured to whitelist or blacklist the serving of specific file types?  What happens if you create an entirely new site on the server with no application whatsoever, just an HTML page and the file to be downloaded.  If you still get the same error then it's a web server configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set up a directory online, where you can host the file.

I also see that in your `aref` you don't want to type the full path so denote it with a `/hello_world.crx`, but make sure that you've set up a base href:

`<base href="http://yourdomain.com/something/">`

Comment: actually we didn't have domain yet

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the file to remove any spaces e.g. "hello_world.crx" and then change the name in the link code to match.

Comment: yah i have changed the name and tested but no success. If it is rar file it is downloading otherwise it is throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

if a webpage and the downloadable file is in the same location

```
(i.e)
SampleFolder->Download.html
SampleFolder->hello world.crx
```

then try the below

```
<a href="hello world.crx" target="_blank">download</a>
```

If the webpage and the downloadable file in different location

```
(i.e) 
SampleFolder->Download.html
SampleFolder->Downloads->hello world.crx
```

then try the below

```
<a href="Downloads/hello world.crx" target="_blank">download</a>
```